# WCAG 9.2 - Verify that any element with its own user interface is device-independent

Tags: visual-studio-2012, accessibility, wcag2.0

I'm using the accessibility checker in Visual studio 2012

On *** < script > *** tags I get this Warning *WCAG 9.2 - Verify that any element with its own user interface is device-independent.*

The relevent WCAG article http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam68-0.htm talks about alternative keyboard or voice input.

So what exactly am I meant to do? How do I get rid of the warnings? Idealy I'd like to add an attribute to the tag to say 'yeah i've checked it' or something that makes it not a warning anymore.

Comment: Note: the [linked example](http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam68-0.htm) is about WCAG **1.0**.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the WCAG 2.0 link for the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Visual Studio's checker, but that advice is about making sure your site/app can be used without a mouse. Have you tested it with just your keyboard? If you can use all the features with just the keyboard then youve met that requirement and the checker is juat reminding you to do a manual check since it can't determine that automatically.

Also Priority 2 is from the old WCAG 1 guidelines, not version 2 which has been the standard for several years now. Visual Studio might have a setting to check for the new requirements (which still include device-independence).

Comment: It's lighting up on script and css links, what's to test.